# MS Excel VBA - Loop Through Rows and Columns (Skip if Null)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, range

Hello stackoverflow community,

I must confess I primarily code within MS Access and have very limited experience of MS Excel VBA.

My current objective is this, I have an expense report being sent to me with deductions in another countries currency, this report has many columns with different account names that may be populated or may be null.

I currently have a Macro that will open an input box and ask for the HostCurrency/USD Exchange rate, my next step will be to start at on the first record (Row 14; Column A-K contains personal info regarding the deduction) then skip to the first deduction account (deduction accounts start at column L and span to column DG) checking if each cell is null, if it is then keep moving right, if it contains a value then I want to multiply that value by my FX rate variable that was entered in the input box, and update the cell with the converion. Once the last column (DG) has been executed I want to move to the next row (row 15) and start the process again all the way until the "LastRow" in my "Used Range".

I greatly appreciate any feedback, explanations, or links that may point me towards my goal. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read though this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it without looping.

```
Sub fooooo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mlt As Double
Dim lstRow As Long
mlt = InputBox("Rate")

With ActiveSheet
    lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(14, 12), Cells(lstRow, 111))
    rng.Value = .Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & " <>""""," & rng.Address & "*" & mlt & ","""")")
End With
End Sub
```

If your sheet is static you can replace `ActiveSheet` with `WorkSheets("YourSheetName")`.  Change `"YourSheetName"` to the name of the sheet.

Comment: @scott16150s if you have a large number of rows you will find that this one is quicker than iterating through each of the cells.

Comment: @scott16150s I noticed you tried to mark both as correct.  Mark the one that you ended up using as correct.  i upvoted the other because it was a good answer.  You need to decide which works best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should attempt to write the code yourself and post what you have so someone can try to point you in the right direction. If your range is going to be static this is a very easy problem. You can try something along the lines of:

```
Sub calcRate(rate As Double, lastrow As Integer)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("L14" & ":DG" & lastrow)

    Dim c As Variant
    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Value = c.Value * rate
        End If
    Next

 End Sub
```

This code will step through each cell in the given range and apply the code without the need for multiple loops. Now you can call the `calcRate` sub from your form where you input the `rate` and `lastrow` .

Comment: I would have made lastrow a long but I doubt the OP will have more than 32000 rows.